# need help recursive javascript function

Tags: json, dynamic, recursion, treeview

I want to turn json string

```
       treeNodes =[{managerid:root,Employeeid:01}, 
              {managerid:01,Employeeid:11}, 
              {managerid:01,Employeeid:22}, 
              {managerid:22,Employeeid:33}, 
              {managerid:22,Employeeid:44}];
```

into this json string using javascript.

```
       json={
        id:root,
        children[{
                id:01,
                children[
                        {id:11},
                        {id:22}
                        ]},
                 {
                 id:22,                  
                children[
                       {id:33},
                       {id:44}
                        ]
                        }
```

Can someone help with java script function?

Comment: What do you expect us to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: So "root" is the manager for "01". "01" is the manager for "11" and "22". "22" is the manager for "33" and "44".

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (I assume `root` is a declared variable):

```
var rootNode = {Employeeid:root};
var json = makeJsonNode(treeNodes, rootNode);
// Do something with "json"
// ...

function makeJsonNode(treeNodes, node){
    var jsonNode = { id : node.Employeeid };
    var children = [];
    for(var i=0; i<treeNodes.length; i++){
        if(treeNodes[i].managerid === node.Employeeid){
            children.push(makeJsonNode(treeNodes, treeNodes[i]));
        }
    }
    if (children.length > 0) jsonNode.children = children;
    return jsonNode;
}
```